# Node.js: Iterating which command over an array of binaries

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, atom-editor

An Atom package of mine opens a file in the system's default file-manager. On Linux, I have a array of widely used file-managers which I would like to iterate over running the `which` command and return the path.

The problem with my current script is, that I don't know how to break the iteration. Running this code will log all `which` attempts and will result every available option. Obviously, this is not the purpose of iteration.

**CoffeeScript** (JavaScript below):

```
fileManagers: ['xdg-open', 'gnome-open', 'kde-open', 'nautilus', 'dolphin']    

@loopWhich (result) ->
  console.log "Result: #{result}"    

loopWhich: (callback) ->
    {exec} = require('child_process')

    for fm in @fileManagers    

      console.log "which: #{fm}"    

      exec "which #{fm}", (error, stdout, stderr) ->
        if error is null
          callback stdout
```

**JavaScript** (auto-generated by `coffee-script@1.9.2`):

```
({
  fileManagers: ['xdg-open', 'gnome-open', 'kde-open', 'nautilus', 'dolphin']
});    

this.loopWhich(function(result) {
  return console.log("Result: " + result);
});    

({
  loopWhich: function(callback) {
    var exec, fm, i, len, ref, results;
    exec = require('child_process').exec;
    ref = this.fileManagers;
    results = [];
    for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
      fm = ref[i];
      console.log("which: " + fm);
      results.push(exec("which " + fm, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error === null) {
          return callback(stdout);
        }
      }));
    }
    return results;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its tough because of the async aspect, but I think this should work:

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'

promisify = (name, fn, args...) ->
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    cb = (err) -> if err then reject err else resolve name
    fn.apply null, args.concat(cb)

thenHandler = (name) -> console.log name

fileManagers.forEach (filem) -> promisify(filem, exec, "which #{filem}").then thenHandler
```

The error cases will be ignored, and a successful execution should log to the console. If you want the actual successful one, you'll have to wrap all of the Promises in another Promise and use a different `.then` handler to resolve the over-arching promise with the correct result:

```
fileManager = new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  fileManagers.forEach (filem) ->
    promisify(filem, exec, "which #{filem}").then (name) -> resolve name
```

If more than one attempt is successful it will only resolve with the first one.